# OnKeyDown method does not fire when I press enter

Tags: android

I need to capture when the usario typing enter in a Text View Autocomplete called `textOrigem`. Below is my code,I debug and it comes when I press any key less enter. The autocomplete text view is with the property `android:clickable = "true"` but still does not enter the method if I dial enter.

```
    textOrigem.setKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyUp(View view, Editable text, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyOther(View view, Editable text, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(View view, Editable text, int keyCode,
                KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Log.d("Key", "enter_key_called");
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int getInputType() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void clearMetaKeyState(View view, Editable content, int states) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: Try logging the key code. Maybe it's something other than what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try TeextView.OnEditorActionListener? Override onEditorAction and in it switch by View.getId if you have few textviews.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with setting key listeners in Android, but taking a quick look at the doc I notice [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/KeyListener.html#getInputType()) little bit for `getInputType`:

> Return the type of text that this key listener is manipulating, as per InputType. This is used to determine the mode of the soft keyboard that is shown for the editor.
>   If you return TYPE_NULL then no soft keyboard will provided. In other words, you must be providing your own key pad for on-screen input and the key listener will be used to handle input from a hard keyboard.

My guess is `no soft keyboard will be provided` is taken literally, which might explain why the Log is not being fired. If not add logs to the other methods as well to see if any of the other ones also fires.

Trying doing this:

```
    @Override
    public int getInputType() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return TYPE_CLASS_TEXT;
    }
```